# What does "cd -P" / "pwd -P" code do that "$(basename -- "$BASH_SOURCE")" does not?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am reading a environment variable setup shell program for spark. I don't quite understand this part.

Codes are shown below:

```
# resolve links - $0 may be a softlink
this="${BASH_SOURCE:-$0}"
common_bin="$(cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$this")" && pwd -P)"
script="$(basename -- "$this")"
this="$common_bin/$script"

# convert relative path to absolute path
config_bin="`dirname "$this"`"
script="`basename "$this"`"
config_bin="`cd "$config_bin"; pwd`"
this="$config_bin/$script"

export SPARK_PREFIX="`dirname "$this"`"/..
export SPARK_HOME="${SPARK_PREFIX}"
export SPARK_CONF_DIR="${SPARK_CONF_DIR:-"$SPARK_HOME/conf"}"
# Add the PySpark classes to the PYTHONPATH:
export PYTHONPATH="$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH="$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH"
```

In the first part it is said by comment that the part is to resolve the links, and in the second part, it is said to convert relative path to absolute path.

But I don't see any difference between these 2 "this": `this="$common_bin/$script"` and `this="$config_bin/$script"`. I think first 4 lines already resolve link and give variable "this" an absolute path, why the shell does the same thing again in the second part(commands after the second comment)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: btw, those just look like regular shell variables, not environment variables.

Comment: BTW, one question to a question. Asking what the `--`s do is perfectly fine, but it should be **its own** question. (That said, you can find the answer yourself if you look through [the POSIX utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the script's intention seems to be exactly what Charles has mentioned, the code has an issue that would make both `common_bin` and `config_bin` set to the same value.

The issue is on line 5:

```
 this="$common_bin/$script"
```

That would make `this` point to the physical path of the script, obtained from `pwd -P` earlier.

Then, on line 8, `config_bin` is being set to the `dirname` of `this`, which would be the physical path, not the one with symlink unresolved:

```
 config_bin="`dirname "$this"`"
```

So, both `config_bin` and `common_bin` will end up getting the same value.  I don't see either of the variables used anywhere else in the script and hence not sure what the author's real intent was.  It does appear that the following section of code isn't required at all:

```
# convert relative path to absolute path
config_bin="`dirname "$this"`"
script="`basename "$this"`"
config_bin="`cd "$config_bin"; pwd`"
this="$config_bin/$script"
```

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. These 2 "$this" have the exactly the same value. I don't understand why the author set the $config_bin and set $this again. I posted complete file and no more codes in the file.

Answer (score 1):

`config_bin` trusts the script's view of its source location to be correct. This is allowed to be a *logical* location.

`common_bin` goes to substantial lengths to get a *physical* location (not including any symlinks).

---

Let's say that this script is `/opt/foobar-1.23/bin/something`.

If you have a symlink to `foobar-1.23` at `/opt/foobar`, and ran your script as `/opt/foobar/bin/something`, then `config_bin` will contain `/opt/foobar-1.23/bin`. By contrast, `common_bin` will include `/opt/foobar/bin`.

Thus, you would want to use `"$config_bin"` when you want to write a path that refers specifically to the version of the software currently in use at the time when the above script is running; whereas you'd want to use `"$common_bin"` when you want to write a path that will always refer to the version of the software that's then pointed to by the symlink, *even if that version is different from the one that was running at the time when the variable was evaluated*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Charles, it helps me understand physical path. I still have a question as @codeforester said. In line 5, "$this" is already set as physical path. There is no need to get $config_bin and then reassign a value to $this in line 10. These 2 $this have the exactly same value. I don't understand why the author writes second block in the shell program.